# Python regex: Turn "ThisFileName.txt" into "This File Name.txt"

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add a space before every capital letter, except the first one.

Here's what I have so far, and the output I'm getting:

```
>>> tex = "ThisFileName.txt"
>>> re.sub('[A-Z].', ' ', tex)
' his ile ame.txt'
```

I want:
   'This File Name.txt'

(It'd be nice if I could also get rid of .txt, but I can do that in a separate operation.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Key concept here is backreferences in regular expressions:

```
import re
text = "ThisFileName.txt"
print re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', text)
# Prints: "This File Name.txt"
```

For pulling off the '.txt' in a reliable way, I recommend `os.path.splitext()`

```
import os
filename = "ThisFileName.txt"
print os.path.splitext(filename)
# Prints: ('ThisFileName', '.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2', 'TheFileName.txt')
```

EDIT: StackOverflow eats some \s, when not in 'code mode'... Because I forgot to add a newline after the code above, it was not interpreted in 'code mode' :-((. Since I added that text here I didn't have to change anything and it's correct now.

Comment: add another backslash: re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', '\\1 \\2', text)...the one is interpreted as an escape sequence...from the documentation: Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

Comment: was not really my fault I think, fixed I anyhow. (See my EDIT: comment)

Comment: ahh: and thanks for notifying me. I would not have looked at this post again.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible regular expression using a look behind:

```
(?<!^)([A-Z])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to do if the filename is `Hello123There.txt`. So, if you want a space before all capital letters regardless of what precedes them, you can:

```
import re

def add_space_before_caps(text):
    "Add a space before all caps except at start of text"
    return re.sub(r"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", " ", text)

>>> add_space_before_caps("Hello123ThereIBM.txt")
'Hello123 There I B M.txt'
```